# "Call to undefined function" in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, localhost

I ran into problem but I couldn't resolve the issue. I read so many post and reset WordPress and using Xampp. I don't know why everything is messed up. Build system even not showing php in sublime text 4.

When I ran my local host it gives:

[image: error].

My theme folder is [here](https://gofile.io/d/DM2zsm). I know there are questions have been asked but they are somehow different.

```
<h1><?php bloginfo('name') ?></h1>
```

Comment: No idea why that doesn't work but have you tried using [get_bloginfo()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/)

Comment: @B001ᛦ no i didnt. i was following udemy course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're accessing your theme files from the browser. I can see from your URL that you're accessing your theme `index.php` file directly. This is bypassing WordPress and the functions it makes available to you.

Ensure your custom theme is active within the WordPress admin area, and then visit your WordPress website url: `http://localhost/warda/wordpress/`. This will load WordPress and then WordPress will load your theme. You should no longer have the error.

---

For example, suppose you have an `index.php` file that contains:

```php
<?php

function custom_function() {
    echo 'Hello, World!';
}

require __DIR__ . '/extra.php';
```

And an `extra.php` file that contains:

```php
<?php

custom_function();
```

If you open `index.php` in the browser it will register a function called `custom_function`, then load `extra.php` and then execute the function. It will output `Hello, World`.

If you open `extra.php` in the browser, it will attempt to execute `custom_function`, but because it has not been defined yet, it will throw an "undefined function" error.

This is essentially what is happening with your WordPress theme.

Comment: still not working after activating the theme.

Comment: @wardahamk what URL are you visiting in your browser?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected single-quoted string "/extra.php" in C:\xampp\htdocs\warda\wordpress\wp-content\themes\My first custom Theme\hello.php on line 7

Comment: https://localhost/warda/wordpress/wp-admin/themes/My%20first%20custom%20Theme/index.php

Comment: @wardahamk As Christopher said, you can't go directly to the theme files. They're not for direct access. Turn the theme on and go to https://localhost/warda/wordpress/.

Comment: @wardahamk Remove `hello.php` and `extra.php` as these are not relevant. I provided those as example of your issue, you should not be adding them to your theme... Also, load up the URL of your WordPress website, not your theme directly as my answer suggested.

Comment: @ceejayoz now i understand may be direct link of the theme causing issue. but last night it was working. :( I am confused

Comment: @ChristopherGeary ok let me try this one too.